# Can a cell phone app in Windows Phone GET TEXT from another app?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I want to build a cell phone app (app#1) in Windows Phone who GETs TEXT from another app (app#2).
I can not control app#2.
The idea is to get text (plain text from app#2's window content) programmatically from apps like Whatsapp, email apps or a browser.
Is this a doable app? Can this be done?.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: no, you can't. windows phone isn't that insecure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible.

You cannot access any data/content from another app unless that data has been specifically shared to your app by the user (e.g. from using the built-in share functionality in the OS).